# Make element not take up more space than it's allocated

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar with a set width and height. The problem is, it's supposed to be on the right but it takes up space on the left too like a block. However, I've set the display to inline but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. How can I make the div take up no space on the left?

Part of the CSS:

```
div#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 256px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline;
    clear: none;
}
```

JSFiddle for the whole page: http://www.jsfiddle.net/9tW2U

Comment: Fiddle looks ok to me. The sidebar is on the right side. Display:block should be ok, too. If any child element however is larger than the sidebar, you might want to use the overflow property.

Comment: when you add float property element displays  like block element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of either `#sidebar` or `#mainbox` is 3px to big to fit next to each other in `#page`. Take 3px of the width of `#sidebar` or `#mainbox` and it will fit.

By the way, `display: inline` doesn't have anything to do with it because you are allready using floats.